# Using Valgrind with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, valgrind

To run a program, I add an `LD_PRELOAD` variable before the command to load a specific library for instrumentation. So the command looks like

```
LD_PRELOAD=foo.so ./run_program
```

In order to use valgrind, If I run `valgrind LD_PRELOAD=foo.so ./run_program`, I get:

```
valgrind: LD_PRELOAD=foo.so: No such file or directory
```

And if I run `LD_PRELOAD=foo.so valgrind ./run_program`, the loaded library doesn't come into effect. So, I would like to know how to attach valgrind to the program with the loaded library. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LD_PRELOAD before both Valgrind and the guest executable.

Valgrind expects the first non-valgrind argument to be the application to be run (either a script or an ELF executable binary).

For example, running the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

print $LD_PRELOAD
```

$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc.so.6 valgrind -q ./sh
/lib64/libc.so.6

There is no way to "attach" Valgrind to a running executable. It does not use ptrace like debuggers (gdb, lldb and udb for instance).

More details on what is going on are [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/31845078/) and the [full thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/valgrind-users/?viewmonth=201401&viewday=14)

Finally, if you run valgrind with -v you should see something like this (there is a lot of output so I've trimmed a lot). The example below was run with

valgrind -d pwd
export LD_PRELOAD=./myprint.so

```
--18766:1: aspacem (0,4,5) /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--18766:1: aspacem (1,49,3) /usr/bin/pwd
--18766:1: aspacem (2,66,3) /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
[memory map]
```

memcheck was exec'd by valgrind, and memcheck then mmap'd the guest (pwd) and ld.so, then it started executing the guest, which will start loading dependencies.

```
--18766:1: aspacem (0,4,5) /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--18766:1: aspacem (1,49,4) /usr/bin/pwd
--18766:1: aspacem (2,66,4) /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
--18766:1: aspacem (4,162,5) /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--18766:1: aspacem (5,216,5) /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--18766:1: aspacem (6,274,8) /home/paulf/scratch/valgrind/cachegrind/tests/myprint.so
--18766:1: aspacem (7,337,0) [free slot: size=17  next=0]
--18766:1: aspacem (8,358,5) /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
[more detailed memory map]
```

Here the guest has loaded the libs listed in LD_PRELOAD (myprint.so and also core and memcheck, which valgrind added to LD_PRELOAD before execing memcheck). It has also loaded libc.so because pwd has a link dependency on it.

Comment: Yes, but the question is, where to put valgrind command.

Comment: After LD_PRELOAD

Comment: @PaulFloyd asker already said that doesn't work.

Comment: I guess that an absolute path might make the difference.

Comment: @user253751 Putting LD_PRELOAD in the right place is always going to be a good start.

Comment: @PaulFloyd yes, read the question. They tried it both ways. But not with an absolute path, but do you really think that makes a difference or is it wild speculation?

Comment: There are too many unknowns to be sure. If the OP's foo.so is in a 'well known' location like /lib or if LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to it or the guest is compiled with an appropriate r(un)path, then no path is requied with LD_PRELOAD. Otherwise a path (relative or absolute) is needed. There are further restrictions for suid/sgid executables. See man ld.so - this is all done by the link loader.

Comment: It doesn't work because LD_PRELOAD will also affect the valgrind executable, and it could cause weird stuff happening.

Comment: @Fayeure are you just making that up or do you actually have a clue about how Valgrind works?